# class diagram uml: concrete class and generic classes

Tags: generics, uml, class-diagram

I have a generic class and many classes that uses that generic

```
public abstract class BaseEntity<Entity> {
    public int id;
    public abstract Entity index();
}
```

example of two classes

```
public class ClassA extends BaseEntity<ClassA>{
    public ClassA(int i) {
        id = i;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "I am a ClassA, my id is " + id;
    }

    @Override
    public ClassA index() {
        return this;
    }
}
```

and the other class

```
public class ClassB extends BaseEntity<ClassB>{
    public ClassB(int i) {
        id = i;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "I am a ClassB :D, my id is " + id;
    }

    @Override
    public ClassB index() {
        return this;
    }
}
```

Now how would I go about representing this in uml? right now I put the `BaseEntity` class as apstract, and added a small rectangle in top with dotted border and `Entity` inside it. My problem is the line between `ClassA` and `BaseEntity`. I looked around and found people putting a dotted line with `<bind Entity > ClassA>`. This seems logical to me but why is the line dotted as if it was an interface? wouldn't it be continuous?

my current implementation:
[image]

Comment: If you want to understand how to make a UML Class Diagram, better don't "look around" for what "people are putting" on their diagram, but look up a good UML textbook or the UML specification. Your "bind Entity > ClassA" doesn't have any general meaning.

Comment: Thank you! you are probably right. I have taken a class in the bast about UML design but we didn't get into generics at all. By looking around I meant that I looked at UML diagrams close to our project but found it unhelpful. I found the bind sentence in so many resources such as http://www.eclipse.org/modeling/mdt/uml2/docs/articles/Defining_Generics_with_UML_Templates/article.html

Comment: The correct notation for a class to be bound to a *template class* (or "parametrized" class) in UML Class Diagrams is shown in 
https://www.uml-diagrams.org/class.html#class-template.

Notice that the relationship between the bound class and the template class is visually expressed with a UML *Realization Dependency* arrow that is stereotyped with «bind». In addition to this stereotype keyword, the binding, in your example <Entity -> ClassA>, is expressed in left/right angles as an annotation to the arrow. However, in your example, you do have a second relationship: ClassA extends Entity.